# Como descobrir se a lista está cheia?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos

O método abaixo é para inclusão de um livro em uma lista. Retorna 1 se o livro já existe na lista, 0 se não existe na lista e pode ser inserido e 2 seria para lista cheia. Estou tentando testar se a lista está cheia mas não sei como. Alguém pode me ajudar?

```
public class ListaDeLivros
{
    private int proximoLivre;
    private int i;
    private Livros osLivrosDaLista[];
    private int capacidade;
    public ListaDeLivros(int proximoLivre, Livros osLivrosDaLista[],int capacidade){
        this.proximoLivre=proximoLivre;
        this.osLivrosDaLista=osLivrosDaLista;
        this.capacidade=capacidade;

    }

    public ListaDeLivros(int capacidade)
    {
        this.capacidade=capacidade;
        osLivrosDaLista=new Livros[capacidade];
    }

    public void setproximoLivre(int proximolivre){
        this.proximoLivre=proximolivre;
    }

    public int getproximoLivre(){
        return proximoLivre;
    }

    public void setcapacidade(int Capacidade){
        this.capacidade=Capacidade;

    }

    public int getcapacidade(){
        return capacidade;

    }

    public int ListaDeLivros(Livros livroAIncluir)
    {

        if(capacidade > proximoLivre)
        {
            for(i=0;i<proximoLivre;i++)
            {
                if(livroAIncluir.getTitulo().equals(osLivrosDaLista[i].getTitulo()))
                {
                    //System.out.println("titulo já existente!");
                    return 1;
                }

            }

            osLivrosDaLista[proximoLivre] = livroAIncluir ;
            proximoLivre++;
            return 0 ;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A sua pergunta é um [**problema XY**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/132). Você quer saber como determinar se a sua lista de livros está cheia. Mas na verdade o seu problema real é que você não sabe como definir uma lista de livros que seja utilizável.

Usar arrays desse jeito, tendo que rastrear qual parte foi utilizada ou não ou onde você insere um elemento, saber se vai ou não estourar e coisas semelhantes é uma tortura penosa, dolorosa e desnecessária. Ao invés de sofrer com isso, use listas e tudo vai ficar mais fácil. Basta usar a classe [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) sem precisar acrescentar nada, que ela já faz tudo isso que você quer e muito mais, com um desempenho espetacular e já tendo sido testada, retestada e exercitada de todas as formas possíveis zilhões de vezes. Ao invés de [**reinventar a roda quadrada**](http://desciclopedia.org/wiki/Gambi_Design_Patterns#Reinvented_Square_Wheel_Helper), use aquilo que a biblioteca padrão já te oferece prontamente.

Você usaria assim:

```
Livro chapeuzinhoVermelho = ...;
Livro oPequenoPrincipe = ...;
Livro oMagicoDeOz = ...;

List<Livro> meusLivros = new ArrayList<>();
meusLivros.add(chapeuzinhoVermelho);
meusLivros.add(oPequenoPrincipe);
meusLivros.add(oMagicoDeOz);

System.out.println(meusLivros.size()); // Vai mostrar 3.
```

Ah, e note que coloquei o nome da classe no singular (`Livro`) e não no plural (`Livros`). Em geral, é boa prática usar nomes no singular, ainda mais considerando que cada instância representa um livro apenas.